# How to call_user_func_array inner method

Tags: php, arrays, object, callback, call-user-func-array

I need to run correctly something like this:

```
$anchor->get_by_number(49)->set_value("hello");
```

Where the object name, methods, and parameters are variables:

```
$object = 'anchor';
$method1 = 'get_by_number';
$params1 = array('49');
$method2 = 'set_value';
$params2 = array('hello');
```

Using `call_user_func_array`, or maybe somebody knows the alternatives.

Comment: Added call_user_func_array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of PHP 5.6 you can use argument unpacking `...`:

```
${$object}->$method1(...$params1)->$method2(...$params2);
```

To do it with `call_user_func_array`, just nest them:

```
call_user_func_array(array(call_user_func_array(array(${$object}, $method1), $params1),
                                                                  $method2), $params2);
```